# Invalid formula error in R - xtabs function giving environment issure

Tags: r, dataframe, stat

When trying to run this (or any other) command

> xtabs(ugdata$response, ugdata$Equity, data=ugdata)

I keep receiving this error

> Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

I have been looking around all day, including similar posts on this website, but I cannot find a solution to help me fix this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `xtabs` expects the first argument to be a `formula` object, not a vector. Take a look at `?formula` to learn how to make one

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in the syntax. Please try:

```
    xtabs(ugdata$response ~ ugdata$Equity, data = ugdata)
```